# R shiny: how to create a dynamic list with names and values

Tags: r, list, shiny

I want to create a dynamic list with the names and values based on user inputs. I need to pass a list with the names of each factor as well as two values for each factor to a function.For example,

```
     factor.names=list( A=c(-1,1),B=c(-1,1),C=c(-1,1),D=c(-1,1) ) )
```

The code below changes the factor values but leaves the names as nf1,nf2 etc.

```
    if(input$fac==2){

      names<-list(nf1 = c(input$l1,input$h1),nf2 = c(input$l2,input$h2))
    }
```

I have tried using

```
    names<-list(input$nf1 = c(input$l1,input$h1), input$nf2 = c(input$l2,input$h2))
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
     Error in source(file, ..., keep.source = TRUE, encoding = checkEncoding(file)) :         
     C:\Users\Fred\Documents\App/server.R:49:59: unexpected '='
    })        
       names<-list(n1 = c(input$l1,input$h1),input$nf2 =
                                                          ^
```

I have also tried

```
     n1<-reactive({
      as.character(input$nf1)
    })        
      names<-list(n1 = c(input$l1,input$h1),n2 = c(input$l2,input$h2))
    }
```

But the names just stay as n1, n2 etc.

Any help or advice on the topic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd try to save values to tmp variables from input, e.g. input_names <-c(input$nf1, ...) and input_values <- c(input$l1) and then assign to our list.

Comment: Have a look at the renderUI / uiOuput features  here is an example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: try `names_list <- list(); names_list[[input$nf1]] <- "value"`